# EF 7, prevent context automatically fills join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, ef-core-7.0

in EF 7, I have two models and a join table(AB is the join table model!)

```
public class A
{
    public int Id;
    public ICollection<B> Blist;
    public ICollection<AB> ABlist;
    ....
}
public class B
{
    public int Id;
    public ICollection Alist;
    public ICollection<AB> ABlist;
    ...
}
public class AB
{
    public A A;
    public B B;
}
```

When I want to save an entity of type A that has a few items in its nested children(`Blist`),
it fails because EF core automatically fills `ABlist` from `Blist`.

Even if I change the state of all items in `Blist` and set it to Detached, still the filling process happens.

The only way is to temporarily set `Blist` to null and after adding/updating roll it back which is so not good. Any suggestions?

Comment: EF will indeed automaticalt fill in related objects that are currently in state. Why is this a problem? It won't alter them, it just populates the navigation properties. Please explain what specific problem this is causing that you want to prevent it.

Comment: i want to manipulate data by my self and when i want to save model, it'll throw exception.

Comment: In that case I don't understand your scenario. Please show some code, with more realistic class names and some data, and explain exactly what exception is thrown and on which line of code.